# How to get distance between me and some facebook user?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-c#-sdk, fql.multiquery

Is it possible to find the smallest distance between me and some User A?
Just imagine:
User A knows someone, who knows someone, who knows someone, ... who knows someone that knows User B.
And I know this user B.

Will the Facebook API allow me to find all these Facebook users between User A and User B?
Or will I have to write my own algorithm to find the shortest distance between me and User A?
Maybe that kind of algorithm already exists...

I can imagine:
If that kind of User B does not exists, then Facebook API or software which cares about this problem will take a long time and maybe it will crash the system.

If that kind of User B exist, then algorithm should also find another that kind of User B in order to compare and get the smallest distance between me and User A!

So how to solve this problem?

Comment: You may also don't worry about another that kind of user B, don't worry about smallest distance between User A and just find one that kind of User B.

Comment: _“Will the Facebook API allow me to find all these Facebook users between User A and User B?”_ – no, it won’t. And with the current changes introduced with API v2.0, you will not even get all friends of the current app user any more, but only those that are already users of your app as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is called degree of separation. With the current limitations in Facebook API v2.0 and above this will not be possible.